# CASE WHEN creating duplicate rows

Tags: sql, case

I have a table i need to get data from and need to incorporate adding a CASE WHEN to add data to columns.  I have added CASE WHEN and GROUP BY but cannot get the desired output.  I have looked at other similar questions but the minimal solutions I have seen, none have helped in resolving the issue.

Appreciate any input.

Below is the current query.

```
SELECT
AHCONO  'Company',
AHRIDN  'Order',
AHRIDL  'Order Line',
AHITNO  'Item',
CASE WHEN AHATID = 'DROP' THEN  AHATAV END AS 'DROP',
CASE WHEN AHATID = 'SEASON' THEN AHATAV END AS 'SEASON'
FROM MVXJDTA.MOATTR
WHERE AHCONO = '650'
    AND AHRIDN = '2000000059' 
    AND AHRIDL = '1'
    AND AHATID IN ('SEASON','DROP')
GROUP BY AHCONO,AHRIDN, AHRIDL, AHITNO, AHATID, AHATAV
```

Current Output

| Company | Order | Order Line | Item | DROP | SEASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 650 | 2000000059 | 1 | 1000019-0006 | DROP01 | 'NULL' |
| 650 | 2000000059 | 1 | 1000019-0006 | 'NULL' | NOV 21 |

Desired Output

| Company | Order | Order Line | Item | DROP | SEASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 650 | 2000000059 | 1 | 1000019-0006 | DROP01 | NOV 21 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate the case expressions to eliminate the NULL values, try:

```
SELECT
AHCONO  "Company",
AHRIDN  "Order",
AHRIDL  "Order Line",
AHITNO  "Item",
MAX(CASE WHEN AHATID = 'DROP' THEN  AHATAV END) "DROP",
MAX(CASE WHEN AHATID = 'SEASON' THEN AHATAV END) "SEASON"
FROM MVXJDTA.MOATTR
WHERE AHCONO = '650'
    AND AHRIDN = '2000000059' 
    AND AHRIDL = '1'
    AND AHATID IN ('SEASON','DROP')
GROUP BY AHCONO, AHRIDN, AHRIDL, AHITNO
```

Also note that literal values use single quotes and should not be used for column  aliases, use double quotes as delimiters.